# dlopen() in multithreaded application exit with "Trace/BPT trap"

Tags: c, multithreading, trace, dlopen

I'm trying to load a framework at runtime in a Mac OS X application written in C using the following command:

```
dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/JavaVM",RTLD_LAZY);
```

If I call `dlopen()` from the main thread it works as expected.

When I call it from another thread, the app exit with error: `Trace/BPT trap`

This is the code which calls `dlopen()` from the main thread (and works):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    void *result = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/JavaVM",RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!result) {
        printf("can't open library JavaVM: %s\n", dlerror());
    }
    else {
        printf("library JavaVM loaded\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: **library JavaVM loaded**

This is the code which calls `dlopen()` from another thread (and exit during the call to that function):

```
void *loadJava(void* arg)
{
    void *result = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/JavaVM",RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!result) {
        printf("can't open library JavaVM: %s\n", dlerror());
    }
    else {
        printf("library JavaVM loaded\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_t vmthread;

    struct rlimit limit;
    size_t stack_size = 0;
    int rc = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &limit);
    if (rc == 0) {
        if (limit.rlim_cur != 0LL) {
            stack_size = (size_t)limit.rlim_cur;
        }
    }

    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (stack_size > 0) {
        pthread_attr_setstacksize(&thread_attr, stack_size);
    }

    pthread_create(&vmthread, &thread_attr, loadJava, NULL);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&thread_attr);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: **Trace/BPT trap**

Where is the mistake?
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm still a newbie

Comment: Posting as a comment rather than an answer, as I'm not 100% sure of this, but I am pretty sure the JVM expects to be initialized on the main thread, and won't work otherwise. As soon as it starts up it creates a number of its own threads, and makes a number of assumptions about its environment which may include being started on the primeval thread. If anyone can provide a working counterexample, I'm happy to retract my claim.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Thank you for your answer. In [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2147/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003827-CH1-INVOCATION) Apple technical note it is written that: _Embedding a JVM into a native Mac OS X application has one major difference from other platforms: If using AWT, the JVM must not be started on the application's main thread. Many tutorials and documents start the JVM on the main thread, so it is important to recognize this unique requirement of Mac OS X_. Since I need to use AWT, I need to start JVM on another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that dlopen() just isn't thread-safe, so you shouldn't call it under multiple threads.
Or possibly, it isn't dlopen() which isn't thread-safe, but your library's initialization code that runs when it's loaded.

There's no reason to call dlopen under threads, because it won't load the library multiple times.
When you load the same file several times, then the second time does nothing (except incrementing some refcount), and just returns the same handle. So you gain nothing by loading it per thread.

You can use dlmopen() to really load a library multiple times. But it's limited to 15 times.
And even then, you should do it in main() before starting the threads (and give each thread its library handle), not from within the thread.

Comment: Thank you! I've used dlopen() in the main thread and then passed the handle into the newly created thread. It works as expected now.

Comment: By the way, this behavior also occurs if you try to use the `lt_dlopen` libtool wrapper call in a multi thread context.

Comment: Hi there, according to the man page of `dlopen`, the function is thread safe (MT-Safe). Is it correct?